# double click auto fills form field, but does not qualify for the required validator?

Tags: angular, autofill, angular-custom-validators

I have the following formgroup:

```
this.order = new FormGroup({
    City: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    Street: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    DateOfDelivery: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    CreditCard: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,/*Validators.pattern('^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$')*/])
})
```

and the following component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="order">
    <label>City</label>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control" list="City" name="City" formControlName="City" placeholder="Choose City" (dblclick)='dblClickCity($event.target)'>
    <datalist id="City">
        <option value="New York">
        <option value="Berlin">
        <option value="London">
    </datalist>
    <br>
    <label>Street</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Input Street for Delivery"
           formControlName="Street" (dblclick)='dblClickStreet($event.target)'>
    <br>
    <label>Shipping Date</label>
    <br>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name here" formControlName="DateOfDelivery">
    <br>
    <label>Credit Card:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Credit Card here" formControlName="CreditCard">
    <br>
</form>
```

When either the city or street form controls are double clicked the following functions are called and auto-fill the inputs with the user's data:

```
dblClickCity(target) {
    console.log(target.touched);
    target.value = this.city;
}
dblClickStreet(target) {
    target.value = this.street;
}
```

However, the confirm button's status on the bottom of the page remains disabled ([disabled]='!order.valid') and only validates once I manually hit a key on each field.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try calling this.order.updateValueAndValidity() inside the dblClick handlers

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. Still has me manually have to keydown on the 2 inputs in order to validate the formgroup

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Had to manually use the .setValue method and input it into the double click handlers like so:

```
  dblClickCity() {
    this.order.controls.City.setValue(this.city);
  }

  dblClickStreet() {
    this.order.controls.Street.setValue(this.street);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for future reference, if you want to set the values dinamically without creating specific functions you could do something like:

```
 dblClickHandler(event) {
    const control = event.target.getAttribute('formControlName');
    this.order.get(control).setValue(event.target.value);
 }
```